# QGIS and Google Streetview?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, google-street-view

Is there a way to open an (embedded or not in QGIS...) window containing a Google Streetview view at given coordinates using PyQGIS?

Answer (score 1):

I have a very basic script, but it works just on point layers where the  epsg 4326 (lat, lon) coordinates are stored in column as well.

add this script below to your point layer, layer properties-actions (chose type python, and name it):

```
import webbrowser
new= 2
url= "https://maps.google.com/maps?z=18&q=&layer=c&cbll=[% "lat" %],[% "lon" %]&cbp=11,0,0,0,0"
webbrowser.open(url, new=new)
```

use the icon called "Run Feature Action" (You can find next to the "Identify Features" icon

Comment: or check the go2streetview plugin, it may can help

Answer (score 0):

I've made a plugin using a lot of the logic from the [PinPoint](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/pinpoint) plugin and pulled in the x and y coordinates into this function to open up streetview/bing bird's eye:

```
import os
def openStreetViewBird(self, x, y):
        link = 'http://data.mapchannels.com/dualmaps5/map.htm?lat=' + y + '&lng=' + x + '&z=18&slat=0&slng=0&sh=0&sp=0&sz=0&panel=mbsi&gm=0&bm=2&mw=1&be=1&mv=1&md=0&mi=1'
        os.startfile(link)
```